# Angularjs - how to add angularjs-file-upload to meanjs library

Tags: angularjs, file-upload, meanjs

Am trying to implement **danialfarid's** [angularjs-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload) using **meanjs**. But it's not *working*.

Is it possible to use it with meanjs??

Comment: Do you see errors in a console?

Comment: yes. the modules and services from the plugin are not registered from "angular.js".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should be able to use it, it looks like you miss a step in including the angularjs-file-upload module into your project, so here's the steps for including this module or any external angular module in MeanJS Application:

1- after installing angularjs-file-upload file upload via bower with the command:

```
bower install ng-file-upload --save
```

2- you should add reference the angularjs-file-upload.js files in your application layout page, this is done in the file: **config\env\all.js**, you should have the lines like this:

```
assets: {
        lib: {
            css: [
                'public/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css',
                'public/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap-theme.css'               
            ],
            js: [
                'public/lib/ng-file-upload/angular-file-upload-shim.min.js',
                'public/lib/angular/angular.js',
                'public/lib/ng-file-upload/angular-file-upload.min.js',
```

3- then you should include angularjs-file-upload as a dependency in your angular application, this is done in the file: **public\config.js**, add 'angularFileUpload' at the end of the array in this line:

```
var applicationModuleVendorDependencies = ['ngResource', 'ngCookies',  'ngAnimate',  'ngTouch',  'ngSanitize',  'ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ui.utils', 'angularFileUpload'];
```

4- you should be able to use the file uploader in your view now, if not complete also the next step then try again.

5- if you want to use the angularjs-file-upload service in you controller, you should inject the upload service (**$upload**) in your module registeration like this:

```
angular.module('myModuleName').controller('MyController', ['$scope', '$stateParams', '$location', 'Authentication', '$upload',
    function ($scope, $stateParams, $location, Authentication, $upload) {
// your controller code goes here
});
```

6- now you should be apple to use the $upload service from angularjs-file-upload in your angular controller like this:

```
 $upload.upload({
                url: '/serverRouteUrl', //upload.php script, node.js route, or servlet url
                method: 'POST', //Post or Put
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'},
                //withCredentials: true,
                data: JsonObject, //from data to send along with the file
                file: blob, // or list of files ($files) for html5 only
                //fileName: 'photo' // to modify the name of the file(s)                
            }).success(function (response, status) {
                   //success 
                }
            ).error(function (err) {
                   //error
                }
            );
```

That will be all from client side, not that you have to configure your server side app or route(s) to be able to handle requests with file uploads, using a library like [Multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer) will do the trick.

Comment: Thank u. It was quite helpful. What I initially tried was include js files in server layout...

Comment: you are welcome, I'm glad I helped :)
If it answered your question, why not marking as an answer? :)

Comment: I am still unable to use this (been trying for days) could you please provide working code for the view and routes files? Thanks.

Comment: @CharlieTupman, please have a look at https://lucidwebdreams.wordpress.com/2015/04/02/file-upload-on-mean-stack/
I have organized my answer in this blog post, if you still have difficulties, please state which part exactly does not work, and provide error messages you get

Comment: Thanks for the response, really apprciate it. Think I'm waiting for the next post with how to configure scope etc. have been killing myself over this for days haha

Comment: Hi I have followed this on every step and i still get Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'angularFileUpload' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Comment: @user237462 what version of danialfarid/ng-file-upload did you install?
they changed the module name to 'ngFileUpload'

Comment: Ah i see. Maybe im working with a mixture of old and new tutorials and mixed something up. Ive started migrating to Meteor.js and not sure if i want to continue with MEAN. The documentation is awful compared to Meteor.