# Mean.JS and adding external dependencies

Tags: meanjs

I am attempting to add the external dependency ui.codemirror to my Mean.JS 0.4.2 application.

My understanding from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25832660/angularjs-how-to-add-angularjs-file-upload-to-meanjs-library) and [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-codemirror) of the steps is as follows:

- `bower install --save angular-ui-codemirror`
- add dependency on `ui.codemirror` module to `/public/config.js`
- add `/public/lib/codemirror/codemirror.js` and `/public/lib/codemirror/codemirror.css` to the assets in `/config/env/all.js`

However, neither the `/public/config.js`, nor the `/config/env/all.js` file exists.

Is this something that has been changed in version 0.4.2? If so, what are the new corresponding files where this info goes?

If not, what is it that I am missing? I tried creating my own `/config/env/all.js` file and adding the files to the assets, but those files are never sent to the client. I'm pretty stumped, as to how to proceed from here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those files have changed in the recent versions of MEAN.JS.

You should add the paths to angular-ui-codemirror to `config/assets/default.js`. There is no need to create new config files.

***Update:***

**If you're using version 0.3.3** you have to update the `config/env/all.js` file where you place the path to your dependency file and in case it is an angular 3rd party module you also have to inject it in your main angular module which can be done in the file `public/config.js`.

**If you're using version 0.4.2** you have to update the `config/assets/default.js` file where you place the path to your dependency file and in case it is an angular 3rd party module you also have to inject it in your main angular module which can be done in the file `modules/core/client/app/config.js`.

Comment: what about /public/config.js?

Comment: Are you sure you are using version 0.4.2, because I don't think there's a `public/config.js` file in 0.4.2. I believe you are using 0.3.3. The solution is: you can either use 0.4.2 version and update `config/assets/default.js` or keep using the version you are currently using (which I think it's 0.3.3) and update the `config/env/all.js` file.

Comment: I updated the answer to better explain the process for both versions

Comment: My problem is exactly that /public/config.js does not exist, so I do not know where it is that you define the highest-level Angular module's dependencies. All the information I can find is on how to do this in v0.3.3.

Comment: You are right, I forgot to mention that if it is a 3rd party angular module you also have to inject it in your main angular module. I edited the answer once again to reflect that.

Comment: Here is another answer to adding dependencies in the new meanjs : http://stackoverflow.com/a/36032008/6044269