# Setting another Date forma in MEANjs with md-datepicker

Tags: angularjs, datepicker

I am using the md-datepicker directive from angular-material, however i would like to typ in the date, not only choose it from the datepicker. I found the following example code:

```
        angular.module('MyApp')
          .controller('AppCtrl', function($scope) {
          $scope.myDate = new Date();

          $scope.minDate = new Date(
          $scope.myDate.getFullYear()-1,
          $scope.myDate.getMonth(),
          $scope.myDate.getDate());

          $scope.maxDate = new Date(
          $scope.myDate.getFullYear()+1,
          $scope.myDate.getMonth(),
          $scope.myDate.getDate());    })

          .config(function($mdDateLocaleProvider) {
            $mdDateLocaleProvider.formatDate = function(date) {
            return date ? moment(date).format('DD.MM.YYYY') : '';
           };

          $mdDateLocaleProvider.parseDate = function(dateString) {
            var m = moment(dateString, 'DD.MM.YYYY', true);
            return m.isValid() ? m.toDate() : new Date(NaN);
          };
         });
```

my problem now is where to use the .config section in a MEANJS yeoman generator application. I couldnt find anything. Does someone did this so far?

Comment: So far i set it in my controller like and moment is installed and injected but somehow it cant be found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're having trouble loading the md-datepicker files and get it to be loaded into MEAN.JS check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34985274/mean-js-and-adding-external-dependencies/34988797#34988797).

However if you are already correctly loading your files into your app and you just want to access the config block of the app you can do so by accessing the file located in `/modules/core/client/app/init.js`, and in this code block just add the logic needed:

```
// Setting HTML5 Location Mode
  angular
    .module(app.applicationModuleName)
    .config(bootstrapConfig);

  function bootstrapConfig($compileProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider, $mdDateLocaleProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');

    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('authInterceptor');

    // Disable debug data for production environment
    // @link https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/production
    $compileProvider.debugInfoEnabled(app.applicationEnvironment !== 'production');

    // md-datepicker configuration
    $mdDateLocaleProvider.formatDate = function(date) {
        return date ? moment(date).format('DD.MM.YYYY') : '';
    };
    $mdDateLocaleProvider.parseDate = function(dateString) {
        var m = moment(dateString, 'DD.MM.YYYY', true);
        return m.isValid() ? m.toDate() : new Date(NaN);
    };
}

bootstrapConfig.$inject = ['$compileProvider', '$locationProvider', '$httpProvider', '$mdDateLocaleProvider'];
```

Don't forget to inject `$mdDateLocaleProvider` in the config block.

Comment: thank you, i think this is exactly what i need. Ill check it out and than show if this was helpfull.

Comment: Thanks again, it took me a while to come back to this problem, since we have a launch and the dateformat was somewhat of not a priority in the last month. But with your code here, i was able to let the picker use the format we would like. One problem was to install moment.js on the Mean.js applicaton. This helped a lot: [HowTo: Add Moment.js to a MEAN.js Project](http://zklinger2000.github.io/blog/2016/03/22/add-momentjs-to-meanjs). Thanks!