# How to use a custom .config filein MEANJS

Tags: angularjs, meanjs

I refering to this post [changing md-datepicker format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32566416/change-format-of-md-datepicker-in-angular-material/39587570?noredirect=1#comment66485938_39587570)

It is exactly what i need, but so far i wasnt able to use the solution, because i didnt get where to put the .config (Im using the MEANSJ yeoman generator app)

Does someone have an idea about where to put it?

Comment: You asked a similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39568360/setting-another-date-forma-in-meanjs-with-md-datepicker) yesterday, which I already answered. This one can be closed.

Comment: thank you, i think i got lost and ended up with two similar questions.